# How to fix service PORT for minikube - skaffold local environment?

Tags: docker, minikube, skaffold

Currently I am using a local environment with Skaffold + Minikube and every time I start the cluster like this:

`skaffold dev -f='./skaffold-cluster.yaml' --no-prune=false --cache-artifacts=false --status-check=false`

I get a bunch of services that belongs to my skaffold manifests, but each one of this services are exposed with random ports. The ip is the same because minikube have already started.

If I do: `minikube service nice-service --url`  I will get the service with the random PORT.

I want to be able to **fix** this port. But I don't see if this is something that should be consider in k8s configuration / skaffold / minikube / docker ??

Typical use case:
I want to access `mysql` from sequel pro / workbench or any tool... therefor this configurations are saved locally with a port... it would be great to not to have to change the port in this tools, to access to the minikube service of mysql...

Current setup has: Virtualbox in OS system, with minikube and skaffold. Services are being exposed as k8s service node ports.

Is it possible to Fix this port services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the nodePort option:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 30007
```

nodePort is the one exposed by `minikube service my-service --url` by adding this option it will not be random any more, but the port you need.

Comment: I will work on further testing with this option, but certainly it could be the answer, in the next couple of hours will make some test

Comment: You should also be able to set NodePort on the service, I guess... But this would probably mean you'd have different development and production versions... https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport